# Why is the limit of a sequence wrong based on the following condition?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\{b_{n}\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ be $$b_1=1$$

$$b_{n+1}=1-b_n$$

Here $n\in \Bbb{N}$. We want to calculate the limit of the sequence, call it $M$. Then $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} b_{n+1}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} 1-b_n=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} 1 -\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} b_n$$.

Then because $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} b_{n+1}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} b_n= M$, then $M=1-M$, then $M=\frac12$

Apparently the result is wrong because $\{b_{n}\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ isn't necessarily convergent so $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} b_{n+1}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} b_n= M$ is likely wrong. But I do not have a compelling reasoning. Could someone give a clear one?

Comment: deleted because of mistake

Comment: @CAGT Wrong. The sequence is $1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0\dots$

Comment: $b_n = 1 - b_{n-1}$. Taking limit on both sides we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = 1 - \lim_{n\to\infty} b_{n-1}$, Hence $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} b_{n-1} = M$ is incorrect.

Comment: But that's the point, neither $\lim b_n$ not $\lim b_{n+1}$ exists.

Comment: @5xum oh, I see, you're right.

Answer (score 3):

What you proved is this:

> If the sequence $b_n$ is convergent, then its limit *must* be equal to $\frac12$.

What you did not prove is:

> The sequence is convegent

Meaning the statement above cannot help you. This, in itself, does **not** mean that the sequence is **not** convergent. The proof is wrong, yes, but having an incorrect proof of a statement does not mean the statement is wrong.

---

For example, I can say "All cats have a brain, I am a cat, therefore I have a brain". This is clearly wrong, since I am not a cat (*or am I*), but we cannot conclude from that that I do not have a brain. The statement "I have a brain" is still unproven, but that in itself doesn't mean it's wrong.

---

In your case, however, the statement **is** wrong. $b_n$ is **not** a convergent sequence. You still have to prove that, and it's easy if you write down a couple of elements in the sequence.

In fact, the sequence you have is the sequence $$1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0\dots$$

which is clearly not a convergent sequence.

Comment: There was a Numberphile video showing 1-1+1-1... = 1/2... not proved but used to prove that 1+2+3+4... = -1/12

Comment: @CAGT I know (and *hate*) that video. One of the worst made by numberphile, because it operates with undefined thongs and doesn't give any context.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you will see that this sequence is "trivial" after some computations. $b_1=1, b_2=0, b_3 = 1, b_4 =0, etc ...$ Your sequence is thus $$1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0...$$ and so on. Obviously it does not converge.